# Change Audio Source of Android Speech Recognizer

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voip, voice

we are working on SpeechRecognization class of android framework.Is there any way that we can Set Audio Source for VoiceRecognization of android we have checked documentation of android but so far we dont have any way we can input VOIP call's audio as source to Speech Recognition.Is that possible. ?

Comment: Perfectly normal to ask now, as no 8 years have passed, but.... did you find a way to do it?